# How can movement speed be set for simple object movement?

Tags: animation, timeline

I finally decided to start actually animating stuff and followed [This YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnvCC4oyvkY). Unfortunately I need my object to remain at a constant speed through its movement (No acceleration/ deceleration.  I.E. start at frame 0 with object moving at 1 foot per second and end with it still moving 1 foot per second.  Currently my only idea is to have it start way out of the scene and end way out of the scene and crop the timeline for the actual animation.

Comment: Speed/acceleration is the result of F-Curve's "Bezier" interpolation. You should switch it to "Linear". See more: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html#settings

Comment: How simple is the animation. If it is simple straight line point a to b, then drivers are a simple option the frame is "time" typing `#frame / 24 + 1` into location.x of an object will make that component move 1 blender unit every second.  It will be at location 1 at frame 0.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the speed to be linear, select the animated object, open the *Dopesheet* window, enable the little arrow button on the horizontal menu bar so only the selected object keyframes will be displayed, press <kbd>T</kbd> to set the keyframe interpolation and choose *Linear*. You can also do it in the *Graph Editor*. Is it what you want?